# GA showing new users and demographic data when site has no tracking code

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

There isn't any GA tracking code on my website page, and ga.js or analytics.js is not present when I inspect the code. The same is reflected in the GA dashboard as an alert, that my page is missing tracking code.

However, my google analytics account shows New Users, separated by Demographics and a couple other graphs with values as high as 50 new users. But in realtime report, it shows 0 users when I am on the website.

I'm unable to interpret this behavior. I was of the understanding that this data comes only when tracking code is present. Is there any other method of feeding data to the site, which I'm not aware of.

This particular GA account was created by someone else an year ago,and I've gained access just now.So I'm also not very sure what all is setup with the account.

Comment: Anybody who knows  the account id can send data to that account. Look in the content reports and select "hostname" as second dimension to see from which server the calls originate.

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. The calls were originating from a subdomain, created for test purposes.